# Razer Megalodon problems

Tags: technical-issues, audio-hardware

I just bought the Razer Megalodons and I've run in to a problem. I cannot transmit while playing audio. I also keep getting "USB bandwidth exceeded" errors. I'm using a 850W power supply and I used to be able to transmit and receive audio simultaneously in the past using a USB headset.

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit for gaming, and my headphones are plugged into a USB 2.0 port.

I've discovered that I can transmit/receive if I plug my G15 keyboard into the USB hub that is part of my monitor, and keep the headphones plugged into the USB ports on the motherboard.

Comment: The "headphones suggestion" part of your question(and the comment) is very subjective and borders on a shopping recommendation, which is considered off-topic here; I would recommend removing that question and sticking with troubleshooting the Megalodon. Also, as a future tip, multiple questions should be asked as, well, multiple questions, as opposed to sticking them under one header. Please [read the FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Alright, I edited the post to remove anything not pertaining to troubleshooting these headphones. Sorry about that.

Comment: What other USB devices are currently plugged in to your computer?

Comment: Deviced plugged into motherboard USB ports: Microsoft mouse, Razer Megalodons, USB extension to my monitor's USB hub.

Comment: Try updating the firmware on them, and see if that helps: http://www.razersupport.com/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=viewdownload&downloaditemid=427&nav=0

Comment: Yes I've done that. I had to grab the drivers from opendrivers.com because the official download on the razer website is gone.

Comment: Sorry can't help, but I have pretty much the same setup and it works without issues.

Comment: @liho1eye Yes it appears that it's just a power issue with the headphones, and I'm not sure if it will ever be resolved. My set up works fine this way, I'll just have to get used to having a cord coming out of the side of my monitor. (unless I buy new headphones.) Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

(Answer as described by OP in comments)

The headphones (and other peripherals) appear to be drawing too much power from the USB hub, so you need to find some way to split peripherals across powered hubs. Using the USB ports on a monitor should work, as should adding a card that contains more USB ports.